# Regex produces different result in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does this regex return an entirely different result in javascript as compared to an on-line regex tester, found at http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

```
var patt = new RegExp(/\D([0-9]*)/g);
"/144444455".match(patt);
```

The return in the console is:

```
["/144444455"]
```

While it does return the correct group in the regexr tester.

All I'm trying to do is extract the first amount inside a piece of text. Regardless if that text starts with a "/" or has a bunch of other useless information.

Comment: Show us some example input with expected result.

Comment: Regular expressions engines are not all the same, the built-in regex libraries vary by language.  That online one uses the ActionScript 3 built-in library, as it is written in Flex/Flash.  That is not the same as the one used by Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex does exactly what you tell it to:

- `\D` matches a non-digit (in this case `/`)
- `[0-9]*` matches a string of digits (`144444455`)

You will need to access the content of the first capturing group:

```
var match = patt.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
}
```

Or simply drop the `\D` entirely - I'm not sure why you think you need it in the first place...

Then, you should probably remove the `/g` modifier if you only want to match the first number, not all numbers in your text. So,

```
result = subject.match(/\d+/);
```

should work just as well.

Comment: You beat me to it, was just about to answer. :)